# Coproduct functor preserves quotient maps

Tags: ring-theory, category-theory

If $S_1$ and $S_2$ are commutative $R$ algebras and $I_1$ and $I_2$ are ideals in $S_1$ and $S_2$ respectively, then it occurred to me that $$S_1 \otimes_R S_2 \to S_1/I_1 \otimes S_2/I_2$$ is a perfectly fine quotient map. When I asked why, I thought that it is $(\pi_{I_1} \otimes 1) \circ (1 \otimes \pi_{I_2})$, and $\otimes$ is the coproduct for commutative $R$ algebras, and the coproduct functor preserves quotient maps in a concrete category.

I was interested to see if my reasoning was sound, and if this was perhaps expressible more generally in category theory (i.e. "coproducts of (some formulation of) quotient maps are (some formulation of) quotient maps"). I understand that the notion of a quotient map is tricky to generalize: sometimes the proper expression is a regular epimorphism but not always(?). So what is the more general version of this thought?

Comment: Colimits preserve colimits.

Comment: @ZhenLin Sorry to ask such a simple question, but what is the right way to think of an epimorphism as a colimit?

Comment: Epimorphisms can be characterised by colimits, but much more importantly, quotients are colimits.

Comment: @ZhenLin I have seen them as coequalizers (in $\mathsf{Top}$ and $\mathsf{Grp}$), but I was not aware this construction is always available in a concrete category. Is it always the same?

Comment: To take a quotient by an equivalence relation is to coequalise. This is not something you can do in every concrete category but you can often do it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Zhen says in the comments, the general category-theoretic principle at work is that colimits commute with colimits. To realize quotienting by an ideal as a colimit, given a commutative ring $R$ and an ideal $I$ of it, let

$$S = \{ (r_1, r_2) \in R^2 : r_1 \equiv r_2 \bmod I \}.$$

There are two maps $$f_1, f_2 : S \to R$$ given by the two projections to $r_1$ and $r_2$, and $R/I$ is the coequalizer of these maps (exercise).